# Cannot save data in SQL using AngularJS and PHP

Tags: php, angularjs, intel-xdk

i have this code that saves a data to sql using angularJS and PHP. Somehow, i cannot save the data to my database. The angularJS code seems right and it says that its successfully saved but when i checked my database, it has nothing. So im guessing that i have the wrong code in my php. Ive done this and that but i cannot find the solution. btw im using intel xdk. here is my code.

IntelXDK

```
<body ng-app="kelvinApp">
<div class="upage vertical-col left" id="mainpage">

        <form name="fileupload" id="fileupload" ng-controller="mainController">

        <div class="widget uib_w_1 scale-image d-margins" data-uib="media/img" data-ver="0">
            <figure class="figure-align">
                <img src="images/Checkmark.png" id="img_display">
                <figcaption data-position="bottom"></figcaption>
            </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="widget uib_w_2 d-margins" data-uib="media/file_input" data-ver="0">
            <input type="file" accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif" id="img_path" name="img_path" ng-model="image_path">
        </div>
        <label class="item item-input widget uib_w_3 d-margins" data-uib="ionic/input" data-ver="0" id="image_id"><span class="input-label">ID:</span>
            <input type="text" name="image_id" ng-model="image_id">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input widget uib_w_4 d-margins" data-uib="ionic/input" data-ver="0" id="image_name"><span class="input-label">Image Name:</span>
            <input type="text" name="image_name" ng-model="image_name">
        </label>
        <label class="item item-input widget uib_w_5 d-margins" data-uib="ionic/input" data-ver="0" id="image_title"><span class="input-label">Image Title:</span>
            <input type="text" name="image_title" ng-model="image_title">
        </label>

    <button class="button widget uib_w_7 d-margins" data-uib="ionic/button" data-ver="0" id="btn_upload" name="btn_upload" ng-click="uploadfile()">Upload</button>       
    </form>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js (angularJS)

```
var app = angular.module('kelvinApp', ['ionic']);
app.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http){
$scope.uploadfile = function() {
    $http.post('http://localhost/Project/addfile.php',
    {
        'image_path' : $scope.image_path,
        'image_name' : $scope.image_name,
        'image_title' : $scope.image_title         
    })
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("Success!");
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        alert("Sorry, Try Again!");
    })
}
});
```

and here is my PHP code, i guess this is where i am wrong. the data isnt saving to database.

```
<?php
require('db.php');

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
global $conn;
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
$image_path = mysql_real_escape_string($data->image_path);
$image_name = mysql_real_escape_string($data->image_name);
$image_title = mysql_real_escape_string($data->image_title);

print_r($data);
$query = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO projectsql.tbl_imgstorage(image_name, image_title, image_path) VALUES(?,?,?)");
console.log("2");
$result = $query->execute(array($image_name, $image_title, image_path));

if($result){
    $array = array('msg' => "Added Successfully", 'error' => '');
    $json= json_encode($array);
    print_r($json);
} else {
    $array = array('msg' => "", 'error' => 'Error in inserting record');
    $json = json_encode($array);
    print_r($json);
}

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have to to be honest here; I don't know anything about angularjs or intel xdk, but I do know PHP and MySQL and can say this:

You don't have an input element holding the `submit` name attribute so everything inside `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){...}` won't execute.

Therefore you will need to rename your submit button from `name="btn_upload"` to `name="submit"`

Then uploading files requires a valid enctype such as `enctype="multipart/form-data"`.

Then you're using `mysqli_` syntax but using a `mysql_` function such as `mysql_real_escape_string()` which does not mix with the `mysqli_` API.

It needs to be `mysqli_real_escape_string()` while passing DB connection to it as the first parameter.

It is unclear though as to which API you are using to connect with and what is inside `require('db.php');`.

Seeing your query `$query = $conn->prepare` suggests either `mysqli_` or PDO.

You need to use the same MySQL API from connection to querying.

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php (check for errors)
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php (check for errors)

---

Sidenote:

I don't know what this function does `ng-click="uploadfile()"`, if it's contributing to the failure of your code or not, as it isn't posted in your question.